# Where to save temporary files for shell scripts

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a script to toggle my screen backlight (mapped to a keyboard shortcut), and I want to save the brightness level so I can restore it when pressing the keyboard shortcut again.

Is there a standard place to save such files? Or should I just create some folder in my home directory to save them there?

[I don't want to save them to `/tmp` because:](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES)

> Programs must not assume that any files or directories in /tmp are preserved between invocations of the program.

Comment: You can use `/var/tmp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux, `/run` or `/var/run` are the standard places for things that are not required to survive a reboot, but mustn't be removed by e.g. `tmpreaper`.  Daemons generally keep their pid files in there, for instance.

If your script runs as an ordinary user, then a dot-directory in that user's home directory is probably the right choice.  That's where applications with persistent settings (e.g. Firefox, GIMP, etc) keep their data.